# How to make counting-down timer to a specific date and time on a web technologies

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

[image]

How can i make a timer countdown set to specific date and time like the date is on June 1, 00:00:00
The code have to show the remaining time to that specific date or time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jQuery Countdown Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or here is a very good free Under construction template with a countdown timer

http://demo.ourtuts.com/site-under-construction/

in the demo the countdown timer is set up as follows(grabbed from source)

```
$(function () {
var austDay = new Date("December 10, 2012 02:15:00");
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay, layout: '{dn} {dl}, {hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, and {sn} {sl}'});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });
```

You can just change the date string

```
var austDay = new Date("December 10, 2012 02:15:00");
```

to suit your need, You can also change the design if you want.

link to download this is at http://www.ourtuts.com/free-site-under-construction-template/